# I am working on a face recognition system using JavaCV. I am using both OpenCV and JavaCV

Tags: opencv, javacv, javacpp

but i could not covert my org.bytedeco.opencv.opencv_coreMat cannot be converted to org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.mat how to resolve this problem

i want to use jar file for my code compatible to convert  org.bytedeco.opencv.opencv_coreMat to org.bytedeco.javacpp.opencv_core.mat and my code run properly